Where exactly was this picture of a huge solar eruption taken?
I saw this picture in Skylab 3 Wikipedia article:

The Sun appears very close in the picture, and it seems like the photo was taken closer to the Sun than the Parker Solar Probe, which is known for its close approach to the Sun.
Where exactly was this picture taken?

for clarity, the dot is only the size of Earth, it is NOT the Earth, it was added for scale.

How did you get "appears very close" from a single picture? The size of an object in a photograph always depends on the zoom level, and we don't have anything else in the image to compare with.

@PaŭloEbermann That's suitably covered by the word "appears"

The photo was taken from the Skylab space station in Earth orbit using a telescope.
The telescope was part of a solar observatory known as the Apollo Telescope Mount, which was specifically designed for observing the Sun. The ATM had instruments that could measure the Sun in X-ray, UV and visible light.
One of the first space telescopes, the ATM had an interesting history. It was developed as part of the Apollo Applications Program, thus the name. This 1960's program studied uses for Apollo hardware after the Moon landing missions were completed. It was originally planned to launch the ATM without crew, attached externally to modified Apollo hardware.
Since the telescopes recorded images onto photographic film, it was planned that crews would visit it on Apollo capsules and do spacewalks to retrieve the film. This methodology carried over to the ATM's use on Skylab, where it was mounted externally to the station, and crews did periodic spacewalks to retrieve the photos from the ATM. Although the Skylab installation included video screens which allowed the crew to view some of the instruments live.
The ATM did not look like a traditional telescope, and actually was a combination of four telescopes and several instruments (thus the name "telescope mount" not "telescope") as seen here:


The ATM was externally mounted and was also used as an attachment point for some of Skylab's solar panels:


Going to the skylab 3 wiki article and clicking on the image reveals the following information:

Photo credit: NASA -
http://spaceflight.nasa.gov/gallery/images/skylab/skylab3/html/s74-15583.html
caption: S74-15583 (July 1973) --- A huge solar eruption can be seen
in this Spectroheliogram obtained during the Skylab 3 mission by the
Extreme Ultraviolet Spectrograph/Spectroheliograph SO82A Experiment
aboard the Skylab space station in Earth orbit. SO82 is one of the
Apollo Telescope Mount experiments. The SO82 A instrument covers the
wavelength region from 150-650 angstroms (EUV regions). The magnitude
of the eruption can be visualized by comparing it with the small white
dot that represents the size of Earth. This photograph reveals for the
first time that helium erupting from the sun can stay together to
altitudes of up to 500,000 miles. After being ejected from the sun,
the gas clouds seem to have come to a standstill, as though blocked by
an unseen wall. Some materials appear to have been directed back
toward the sun as a rain, distinguished by fine threads. At present it
is a challenge to explain this mystery--what forces expelled these
huge clouds, then blocked its further progress, yet allowed the cloud
to maintain its threads. Both magnetic fields and gravity must play a
part, but these curious forms seem to defy explanation based on
magnetic and gravitational fields alone. The EUV spectroheliograph was
designed and constructed by the U.S. Naval Research Laboratory and the
Ball Brothers Research Corporation under the direction of Dr. R.
Tousey, the principal investigator for this NASA experiment. On the
left may be seen the sun's image in emission from iron atoms which
have lost 14 electrons by collision in the sun's million-degree
coronal plasma gas.

So this picture was taken from Skylab while it was in low earth orbit.
